# Weight sensor / load cell not working

Tags: sensors

I just got all my parts together that I needed for my project and put everything together like said here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140303140445/http://cerulean.dk/words/?page_id=42 but the serial monitor gives me all random outputs:

```
analogValue: 865.52
             load: 43.27584
analogValue: 865.54
             load: 43.27717
analogValue: 865.50
             load: 43.27517
analogValue: 865.43
             load: 43.27151
analogValue: 865.32
             load: 43.26601
analogValue: 865.45
             load: 43.27255
analogValue: 865.45
             load: 43.27241
```

So I can't calibrate everything to even continue, what is wrong? I checked all my connections like 50 times and everything is wired up like shown in the tutorial.

Here are my parts:

- INA125P:
  http://www.reichelt.de/INA-125-PA/3/index.html?&ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=147252&artnr=INA+125+PA&SEARCH=ina125p
- Load cell from a simple 5kg kitchen scale (tested it before removing
  and it worked)
- 10 Ohm resistor

Thank you in advanced, Greetings

Comment: Doesn't look random to me. Pretty consistent. Did you calibrate, and update the values for analogvalA and analogvalB?

Comment: It always returns something around 866 - so I can't really set those values.

Comment: Does the value change if you place some weight on it?

Comment: Sometimes - but most of the time not, it stays at like 866.

Comment: I solved it by replacing the resistor with a potentiometer.

Answer (score -1):

You might be driving the amplifier to its limits, and getting a value at its limits.

The INA125 isn't a rail-to-rail amplifier, so if you are wiring it up to ground and +5V as described, its output is limited to be between 0+1V=+1V and 5V-1.7V=+3.3V, so it would be easy to saturate it and bump up against those limits and give you a constant value.

If you are using the 10ohm resistor as the INA125 gain, the gain G=4+60000/10=6004x so the input voltage difference needs to be between 0.00016V and 0.00055V volts to be unsaturated within its output linear range.  If it is outside of those limits, the amplifier will act as a comparator.

You could check this by putting a voltmeter on the output of the amp and measuring what is is and if it changes.  If it isn't near 2.5V when the scale is unloaded and is saturated at the limit of the amp, then you might need to balance the loadcell closer to zero so it doesn't peg the scale, or reduce the amplification.